# jQuery event to fire once on site load

Tags: jquery, fadein, onload

I'm trying to fadein a div only ONCE for when the user lands on the home page. For example, 'Site Home Title' fades in when you land on the site, the you'll navigate across to the About, Contact pages etc, but when you click back on the home page again, 'Site Home Title' will not fade in.

So on the div i've just got :

```
$('#home-title').fadeIn(500);
```

So my problem is that now whenever you go the home page it always fades it... obviously since that's what the code is telling it to do. But what do I add so it only happens once when you land on the home page on the very first time?

[Sorry! More detail description below]

I've got this:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('.faded').hide();
});


$(window).load(function() {     
    $(".faded").each(function(i) {
        $(this).delay(i * 500).fadeIn();  
    });
}
```

So .faded is only attached to the div's on the home page. I was wondering whether it would be possible for jQuery to recognize that if it's on one of the other pages, and you click back to the home page - it's already faded in the elements and so does not need to do it again. However, if the user closes the browser or leaves the site entirely but comes back to it, we could get the .faded div's to fade back in again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If old browsers are an issue, you'll need cookies, and there's a good jQuery plugin [here!](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/)

Otherwise I'd go for localStorage, as it's a little easier to deal with:

```
var elem = $('#home-title');

if (elem.length) {                                  //you're on the first page
    if (!sessionStorage.getItem('HasVisitedFirst')) {  //check if we have been here
        elem.fadeIn(500);                            //if not, fade in  
        sessionStorage.setItem('HasVisitedFirst',true);//and set a value to remember
    }
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/cfybj/1/)

Comment: Hey gave this a go but I still want it to be visible after the first load. Using this it just disappears when I refresh the page.

Comment: Well, yeah! That's sort of the point! Are you expecting it to work every time, or only on the first visit?

Comment: Sorry @adeneo - i attached better description of what i'm trying to get above :)

Comment: @lchong - There's no way to determine whether the users refferer (where they are coming from) is your site or not on the clientside, but on the serverside you could do this. I changed my answer to use sessionStorage as that will clear when the session ends, but the session ends when the browser is closed and not just when the user navigates away or closes the tab with your site, and it's the same for session cookies aswell.

Comment: OOOOO! Ok! so i tested in fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/cfybj/5/) and its pretty much what i'm after but my js file is getting grumpy at me saying that some of the characters cannot be saved because it's not in the correct UTF-8 format?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what back-end your using, you could check to see if a session or other cookie has been set and fadeIn if it is not present.

Since you're using jQuery, there is an easy way to set/get your own cookies. I've put together a quick [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fWTjs/) to show you an example.

Edit:
I should mention, this solution needs the [jquery-cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/) plugin. If you want it to permanently display without fadeIn after the first load, just set the css display property to block (assuming you used css to hide it in the first place):

```
$('#home-title').css('display', 'block');
```

Here is an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fWTjs/2/).

Comment: Thanks for the updated info! :) Would this be right?

      $(function() {if (!$.cookie('.faded')) {
   $('.faded').each(function(i) {
  $(this).delay(i * 500).fadeIn();
});
    $.cookie('.faded', 1);
  }
  else {
    $('.faded').css('display', 'block');
  }
 });​